# How to specify a target entity type with sonata_type_collection

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata Page Bundle to build a set of page with information about items -- one item per page. On each page, I want to include multiple synonyms for the item. I have created a Synonym entity with two fields.

I now want to use an `add()` method within my `configureFormFields` definition to add a reference to my new Synonym entity. The following code yields an error saying that `The current field 'Synonym' is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ''`:

```
            ->add('Synonym', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => "Synonyms",
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
```

... and I have tried modifying the code so it looks like:

```
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'target_entity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Synonym'
            ), array(
```

... which results in the same error.

**How do I tell my admin class that this is a reference to a set of Synonym objects that I want to edit inline?**

Edit:

I have also tried

```
'targetEntity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Synonym'
```

... with no luck. The application is still seemingly having trouble figuring out what the entity I'm targeting is.

Answer (score 0):

An at least partial answer was found in adding an "admin_code" definition to my array, as described at

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html

I still get an error, but it is now at least a different error.